# Variable changes after being used as function parameter

Tags: javascript

I am looping through some elements and then adding new elements which should manipulate these elements when clicked. It's tough to explain, so please have a look at this Fiddle to make it much clearer:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgFcn/3/

The interesting part is this code (pseudocode for the sake of brevity):

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];

    someOtherElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
        testDiv(div); // always refers to the last div because variable is overwritten next loop
    });
}
```

I expect the testDiv call to refer to div 1, div 2, div 3 respectively, but instead, they all refer to div 3 because the variable gets overwritten in the next loop iteration. How can I solve this?

Comment: pls post complete code... What is someOtherElement ?

Comment: Sorry, this is just pseudocode, complete code is in JsFiddle for sake of brevity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a classical problem. Here's how it's usually solved :

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    (function(div){
      someOtherElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
        testDiv(div);
      });
    })(divs[i]);
}
```

To understand both the problem and the solution, you have to know that the scope of a not global variable, in JavaScript, is the call of the function where it is declared. This means that

- in your code, there is only one `div` variable
- in the solution, calling the intermediate functions make different `div` variables

Comment: so someotherElement gets n number of click handlers applied - testDiv() gets called N times whensomeotherElement is clicked ? (where n = div.length)

Comment: @NimChimpsky I hope the fact this is pseudo-code also means there are, in fact, different elements. But this is worth noting in case OP really binds the event N time to the same element (which isn't **so** bad but could be optimized).

Comment: No, my pseudo code is a little misleading. "someOtherElement" is dynamically created each loop, it's not the same element. It's an HTML anchor element which is then added somewhere else on the page. I'm writing code to expand and collapse a div using an anchor.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the clickhandler gets overridden each time, or multiple  different ones get created.

Comment: @NimChimpsky If that were the same element, the listener would be added, there would be no removal nor overriding.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of resolving the issue...

```
function testDiv(d) {
    // this doesn't work as expected, it always shows "Div 3"
    alert(d.innerText);
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.index = i;  
    a.innerText = "[this should point to Div" + (i+1) + "]";
    a.href = "#";
    a.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var tg = e.target || e.srcElement;
        testDiv(divs[tg.index]);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine as well! This is a clever method, I didn't know about it. I don't understand the .index part, I will read about it now.

Comment: Basically, you can add properties to any object at runtime. I am exploiting this behavior :)